# Droid Turbo Bluetooth Microphone with Touchless Controls?

Tags: google-now, motorola-droid, voice-recognition

Can you use a bluetooth microphone to activate the touchless controls on the Droid Turbo? ("The "Ok Google Now" feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. It's built entirely to listen ONLY through its built-in microphones, as it can do so with minimal power drain. Activating touchless control through any normal Bluetooth headset would require that the Bluetooth headset's microphone be always listening and always transmitting to the phone, resulting in a massive power drain to both devices.

The only exception that I'm aware of is the [Motorola Hint](http://www.motorola.com/us/accessories/talk/bluetooth-headsets/moto-hint/moto-hint-pdp.html) Bluetooth headset which is specifically designed for this, as it uses similar technology to the Droid Turbo and Moto X line to always listen with minimal power usage, has its own voice commands, and can tap into the Google Now voice functionality. Presumably, with time, we'll see other devices add the same or similar functionality.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to activate "Ok Google" by pressing a button on a bluetooth device like the SonicRider?

Comment: Looks like you can tweak it out to get the phone to respond to the bluetooth button in a custom way, and launch "Ok Google" on some phones: http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-m8/451856-can-i-make-my-bluetooth-activate-google-now-instead-voice-dialer.html

Answer (score 0):

I have spent an incredible amount of time talking to tech support and *nobody* told me this, because they clearly didn't know.  BTW, it appears there are apps that also do not use the bluetooth mic, and I believe that's due to (my) device's profile as an audio distribution device, which might not include having a mic.